# How can I exit "Quick Mode" on Acer Liquid smart phone?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, launcher, bugs

The Acer Liquid 630 received a Lollipop update in December.

I accidentally launched Quick Mode and now I am not able to exit. If I choose to end QM, the phone asks for confirmation but stays in Quick Mode. Before installation of the Lollipop update, leaving QM was possible.

This problem has been reported also in a recent comment on [How do you take quick mode off Acer Liquid Z3?](http://www.cellphones.ca/answers/how-do-you-take-quick-mode-off-acer-liquid-z3/)

Is there a way to disable or exit QM, or do I have to return to factory settings?

---

I have filed a bug report with Acer now, and resetted my phone to factory settings.

Update: three months later, Acer has not yet replied, but the phone has received two updates since December so maybe it is fixed. I will not test it as I might end up with another factory reset.

Comment: I don't have Acer smartphone, so I don't really know your attempt to exit QM, but have you followed the [official manual from Acer](http://acer-au.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34681/~/how-to-use-acer-quick-mode-on-acer-smartphones)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a factory reset and install everything again, you can download a home launcher from appstore! Set your new home launcher as default then uninstall quick mode(sucks bigtime)... I like my phones new look, i even got rid of the left page on the homescreen. :-)